# Unexpected indent? Why?

Tags: python

When I try to run this script in my Python console, I get an unexpected indent @ s = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(user_agent=MOBILE_USER_AGENT, parser="lxml")

why?

it matches the indent spacing of the rest of the ones?

```
# Used from  https://github.com/philipperemy/Deep-Learning-Tinder/blob/master/tinder_token.py

import re

import requests
import robobrowser

MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Tinder/7.5.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)"
FB_AUTH = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fb464891386855067%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&display=touch&state=%7B%22challenge%22%3A%22IUUkEUqIGud332lfu%252BMJhxL4Wlc%253D%22%2C%220_auth_logger_id%22%3A%2230F06532-A1B9-4B10-BB28-B29956C71AB1%22%2C%22com.facebook.sdk_client_state%22%3Atrue%2C%223_method%22%3A%22sfvc_auth%22%7D&scope=user_birthday%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_education_history%2Cemail%2Cuser_relationship_details%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_likes&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&default_audience=friends&return_scopes=true&auth_type=rerequest&client_id=464891386855067&ret=login&sdk=ios&logger_id=30F06532-A1B9-4B10-BB28-B29956C71AB1&ext=1470840777&hash=AeZqkIcf-NEW6vBd"


def get_fb_access_token(email, password): 
    s = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(user_agent=MOBILE_USER_AGENT, parser="lxml")
    s.open(FB_AUTH)
    f = s.get_form()
    f["pass"] = password
    f["email"] = email
    s.submit_form(f)
    f = s.get_form()
    try:
        s.submit_form(f, submit=f.submit_fields['__CONFIRM__'])
        access_token = re.search(
            r"access_token=([\w\d]+)", s.response.content.decode()).groups()[0]
        return access_token
    except Exception as ex:
        print("access token could not be retrieved. Check your username and password.")
        print("Official error: %s" % ex)
        return {"error": "access token could not be retrieved. Check your username and password."}


def get_fb_id(access_token):
    if "error" in access_token:
        return {"error": "access token could not be retrieved"}
    """Gets facebook ID from access token"""
    req = requests.get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + access_token)
    return req.json()["id"]
```

Comment: Does `    import re` line has tab/4x space before it? If yes, then remove it from every line in file.

Comment: Select all the code snippets and press `shift+tab`

Answer (score 3):

This is very probably an issue with mixing tabs and spaces.

Depending on your editor you should try to search for tab characters.

Another way to fix this could be create a new file and copy paste back from this question.

Then the error should disappear.

Comment: so I did that, and now it's throwing an 'unexpected indent' on the first line: 'import re' lol wut???

Comment: @WillPurcaru If you're copying from your own question, you should be aware that that code *already* has 4 space indentation that should be removed. I also strongly suggest you to take some time, search and study documentation and tutorials about python indentation and code styling.

Comment: Yes true. you must copy paste from the question end remove 4 spaces from each line.
On some editors you just select the entire code and press `shift+tab` and that will unindent